# Can't restart rails server (only hard reset helps)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

Im usuing standart WEBrick server in my development environment

1) I run server via `rails s`

2) Then I do `ctrl-C` to shut it down

3) Use `rails s` one more time and following error appears

[image]

**Therefore, each time I have to restart server, I kill process from /tmp/pids/server.pid and delete .pid file, which is an pain...**

Any ideas why this might happens?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in RubyMine (RM), my suggestion would be to (slightly) alter how you use/control your server.

Instead of opening a Terminal and typing `rails s`, use the available server configuration from RM.

[image: The drop-down menu for configs]

When chosen, it will start your server and give you a new panel just for controlling your server:

[image: server panel]

The cool thing here is that there is a start/restart button (showing the restart icon in my screen shot since I just started the server). When you're ready to restart the server for any reason, just open this panel and click that restart button (or click the stop button and then click the start icon if you prefer).

I've had a few little, niggling issue with RM's implementation of a Terminal but never had issues with my server management from RM using this approach.

I did notice in your original screenshot that you do have two Terminal windows open (Local and Local(1)). If you stick with the Terminal approach to server management in RubyMine, that *may* be part of the issue (I recall getting myself into 'trouble' in particular when I opened multiple Terminal shells in RM)